# Countdown the days and months within Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-math

I know of `date_part('days', age(release_date))`, which will show you days of the age of the `release_date` col (`timestamp`). For example, if the release date is `1994-05-30`, the `date_part` calculation would yield `5 days`.

However, how can I find out from a countdown perspective, ie, for another release. There are `2 days` left till the anniversary of this release hits? Is it just a matter of `365 - date_part('days', age(release_date))`, for example? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose the release date to the current year and subtract the current date from it. Assuming `release_date` is an actual `date`:

```sql
SELECT *
     , (release_date + (date_trunc('year', LOCALTIMESTAMP)
                      - date_trunc('year', release_date)))::date
     - CURRENT_DATE AS days_till_aniversary
FROM   release;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=82794de454c00bc070a718fdbd83e64c)*

There is a reason for `LOCALTIMESTAMP` in one spot and `CURRENT_DATE` in the other. This way, the calculation is done without involving time zones. (Except that either depends on the time zone setting of your session to begin with.) And subtracting dates yields an integer, signifying the difference in days.

Produces negative numbers past anniversaries this year.